# Woocommerce Order detail page generates 500+ queries. Is there a way to reduce the queries per item?

Tags: woocommerce

I am using Query Monitor to check the query count in pages that can't be cached in WooCommerce the cart, checkout and other pages in my account are under 150 queries. However, some of the order details pages has 500+ queries.

The reason for this is that WooCommerce is making 8 queries per item in the order.(Is this normal?)

```
SELECT meta_id as meta_id, meta_key, meta_value FROM vs_woocommerce_order_itemmeta WHERE order_item_id = 647 ORDER BY meta_id

SELECT order_item_id, meta_key, meta_value FROM vs_woocommerce_order_itemmeta WHERE order_item_id IN (647) ORDER BY meta_id ASC
```

Those two are necessary for sure. Then it goes to get the item's product, product meta and taxonomies.

```
SELECT t.*, tt.* FROM vs_terms AS t INNER JOIN vs_term_taxonomy AS tt ON t.term_id = tt.term_id INNER JOIN vs_term_relationships AS tr ON tr.term_taxonomy_id = tt.term_taxonomy_id WHERE tt.taxonomy IN ('product_type') AND tr.object_id IN (3874) ORDER BY t.name ASC

SELECT post_id, meta_key, meta_value FROM vs_postmeta WHERE post_id IN (3874) ORDER BY meta_id ASC

SELECT t.*, tt.* FROM vs_terms AS t INNER JOIN vs_term_taxonomy AS tt ON t.term_id = tt.term_id
INNER JOIN vs_term_relationships AS tr ON tr.term_taxonomy_id = tt.term_taxonomy_id WHERE tt.taxonomy IN ('product_visibility') AND tr.object_id IN (3874) ORDER BY t.name ASC

SELECT DISTINCT t.*, tt.* FROM vs_terms AS t LEFT JOIN vs_termmeta ON ( t.term_id = vs_termmeta.term_id AND vs_termmeta.meta_key='order') INNER JOIN vs_term_taxonomy AS tt ON t.term_id = tt.term_id INNER JOIN vs_term_relationships AS tr ON tr.term_taxonomy_id = tt.term_taxonomy_id WHERE tt.taxonomy IN ('product_cat') AND tr.object_id IN (3874) AND ( ( vs_termmeta.meta_key = 'order' OR vs_termmeta.meta_key IS NULL ) ) ORDER BY vs_termmeta.meta_value+0 ASC, t.name ASC

SELECT t.*, tt.* FROM vs_terms AS t INNER JOIN vs_term_taxonomy AS tt ON t.term_id = tt.term_id
INNER JOIN vs_term_relationships AS tr ON tr.term_taxonomy_id = tt.term_taxonomy_id WHERE tt.taxonomy IN ('product_tag') AND tr.object_id IN (3874) ORDER BY t.name ASC

SELECT t.*, tt.* FROM vs_terms AS t INNER JOIN vs_term_taxonomy AS tt ON t.term_id = tt.term_id INNER JOIN vs_term_relationships AS tr ON tr.term_taxonomy_id = tt.term_taxonomy_id WHERE tt.taxonomy IN ('product_shipping_class') AND tr.object_id IN (3874) ORDER BY t.name ASC
```

All these starts from the standard $order = wc_get_order( $order_id ); line on the order details page

**Question : Is there a filter or another way to loop troughs wc_get_order( $order_id )  without going so deep on the items product taxonomy (cats, tags)?**

My order detail only needs to show the item name (product name) qty, one product meta and the subtotal

Thanks!

Comment: Thanks, I updated it to only 1 question

Comment: The queries that you describe are not due to `wc_get_order( $order_id )`…It's  `$order->get_items()` that is generating that 8 queries by order item, because each order item is a `WC_Order_Item_Product` Object, that includes the order item data and the `WC_Product` Object (with your 6 additional queries). To make that a bit lighter, will require you to make something completely custom, and to rewrite the related template(s).